# What is the meaning of the "stackoverflow-sandbox" tag? Do we still need it?

Tags: support, tags, meta

I notice that a recent question used [stackoverflow-sandbox](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-sandbox). The tag has no description, but I noticed that two of the questions were referring to http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/. Trying to look at that domain, I am redirected to another one that shown me just a blank page.

Is the tag still relevant? It doesn't seem it describes something that actually exist, or an actual concept. Should the tag be removed?

Comment: Never mind; looks like a piece of history now taken over by a typo-squatter.

Comment: See [StatOverflow Ideas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20194) for a reference to the site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried also http://stackoverflow.com/sandbox/, but it didn't work the same. If that is the case, the tag is still about something that doesn't exist anymore. I thought of a typo, but I also thought that two different users, one of which seems to know well the Stack Exchange sites, would not make such an evident typo. `:)`

Comment: Okay, bibim.ly is owned by the same person who created statoverflow.com. I guess it was supposed to be a new project.

Comment: From context I infer that http://data.stackexchange.com replaced statoverflow.com's sandbox function, making the tag obsolete.